# Doctrine Migrations with own database connection instead of using migrations-db.php file

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

I have been trying to use my own **Doctrine\Dbal\Connection** object with Doctrine Migrations, this is what I got so far, but it keeps telling me to supply a **--db-configuration** file, which is not what I want.

```
// CLI script for Doctrine Migrations
$app = require 'bootstrap.php';

$cli = new Symfony\Component\Console\Application('Doctrine CLI');

$cli->addCommands([
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\DiffCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\ExecuteCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\GenerateCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\MigrateCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\StatusCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\VersionCommand()
]);

$helperSet = new Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet([
    // Doctrine\DBAL\Connection $app->getContainer()->db
    'connection' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($app->getContainer()->db),
    'dialog' => new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper(),
]);

$cli->setHelperSet($helperSet);

$cli->run();
```

Exception:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                 
You have to specify a --db-configuration file or pass a Database Connection as a dependency to the Migrat  
ions.
```

Comment: Good question. I stumbled upon a problem to run migrations from my tests, I have already established an in-memory storage and connected to it (via doctrine dbal). 

Now I need to reuse that connection to fill up the contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cli->setHelperSet($helperSet);
```

needs to come before

```
$cli->addCommands([
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\DiffCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\ExecuteCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\GenerateCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\MigrateCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\StatusCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\VersionCommand()
]);
```

so that the helperSet is passed to each of the commands.

Source: I was struggling with this too, and dug through the code to see how it worked until I realized my mistake (which was the same as yours, and possible future visitors to this question.)